# need more understanding on gitblit groovy push script

Tags: java, git, groovy, repository, gitblit

I have below `groovy script`

```
PushCommand push=git.push();
push.setRemote("my remote");
push.setPushAll(); //Push all branches under refs/heads/*.
push.setForce(true); //Sets the force preference for push operation.
push.call();
```

My requirement: `want to push only changes from one gitinstance to other`

`setPushAll` : Is this going to push all repository data all time script executed or just commied changes(I want change only)?

`push.setForce(true)` : What is use of this ? Should I use it in my case ?

Comment: git only pushes the diffs (if data volume is your concern).  and force you can lookup in the man-page (or docs) of git-push http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push

Comment: Thanks, But in my case can you please let me know what happen if i use `setPushAll` & `force=true`, Other side If not ?

Comment: i don't understand what you are after.  this command is like `git push --all --force`.  the docs explain both items.

Comment: `setForce(true)` will override references in the target repo with the references in the source repo.  For your situation this is probably what you want.

Comment: `setPushAll` will push all branches from the source to the target.  This is also probably what you want.

Comment: Last doubt:  (data volume is my concern) is this groovy only pushes the diffs or whole data?

Comment: [C|J]Git only pushes what is not in the target.

Comment: Thanks!! N sorry for silly questions as Newbie in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer what I want to know As in comment

`Git only pushes what is not in the target`

`setForce(true)` will override references in the target repo with the references in the source repo. For your situation this is probably what you want. –  `James Moger`

`setPushAll` will push all branches from the source to the target. This is also probably what you want. –  `James Moger`

you can lookup in the man-page (or docs) of [git-push](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push) -  `cfrick`